# I'm trying to calculate salary in JS where there are two different rates

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to calculate salary where there are two different rates within the same time range:from 10:00-15:00 the rate is 20and from 15:00 to the end the rate is 15.
Link for the whole code: https://replit.com/@barel31/tenbis-calculator#src/App.jsx
So for example if I work from 11:00-16:30 it should calculate the first 4 hours by 20 and the rest by 15 so 4x20 + 1.5x15 = 102.5

```
const calc = () => {
    var hour = 30;
    hour += vehicle === 'Motorcycle' ? 15 : 10;

    const timeStartDec = hoursToDec(timeStart);
    const timeEndDec = hoursToDec(timeEnd);

    const hours = timeEndDec - timeStartDec;

    if (timeStartDec >= 10 && timeEndDec <= 15) {
        // Here are the condition if the shift start before 10:00 and and end before 15:00
        // but the problem is when it won't calculate if the user start after 10:00 or end before 15:00 
        hour += 5;
    }

    const minutes = hours / 60;
    for (var i = 0; i < minutes; i++) {
        break;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p>hours: {hours}</p>
            <p>per hour: {hour}</p>
            <p>wage: {hours * hour}</p>
            <p>dec start: {timeStartDec}</p>
            <p>dec end: {timeEndDec}</p>
            <p>wage: {hours * hour + (tips | 0)}</p>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Where is `vehicle` declared? Also same question for `timeStart` & `timeEnd` ? Would be helpful if there was some kind of snippet to accompany this so that the code can be run, might have a better chance of getting an answer that way too

Answer (score 0):

It is notable that there are six different cases in this problem.

- `starttime < timeRange[0]` and `stoptime < timeRange[0]`
  (e.g. - `timeRange = ['10.00', '12.00']`,`starttime='8.00'` and `stoptime = '9.00'`)
- `starttime < timeRange[0]` and `timeRange[0]< stoptime < timeRange[1]`
  (e.g. - `timeRange = ['10.00', '12.00']`,`starttime='8.00'` and `stoptime = '11.00'`)
- `timeRange[0] < starttime < timeRange[1]` and `timeRange[0] < stoptime < timeRange[1]`
  (e.g. - `timeRange = ['10.00', '12.00']`,`starttime='11.00'` and `stoptime = '11.30'`)
- `timeRange[0] < starttime < timeRange[1]` and `stoptime > timeRange[1]`
  (e.g. - `timeRange = ['10.00', '12.00']`,`starttime='11.00'` and `stoptime = '13.00'`)
- `starttime > timeRange[1]` and `stoptime > timeRange[1]`
  (e.g. - `timeRange = ['10.00', '12.00']`,`starttime='13.00'` and `stoptime = '14.00'`)
- `starttime < timeRange[0]` and `stoptime > timeRange[1]`
  (e.g. - `timeRange = ['10.00', '12.00']`,`starttime='9.00'` and `stoptime = '14.00'`)

So we need to calculate the problem for these six cases.

The easiest way of doing this is getting the hours and comparing them and generating the output.

```
function calculate(starttime, stoptime){
    var timeRange = ['10.00', '12.00']
    var payRange = [15,20]
    var ss1 = getHours(starttime, timeRange[0])
    var ss2 = getHours(starttime, timeRange[1])
    var st1 = getHours(stoptime, timeRange[0])
    var st2 = getHours(stoptime, timeRange[1])
    var p = 0
    //case 1 
    if(ss1>=0 && ss2>=0 && st1>=0 && st2>=0){
        p = (ss1-st1) * payRange[0]
    }
    //case 2 
    if(ss1>=0 && ss2>=0 && st1<=0 && st2>=0){
        p = ss1 * payRange[0] + st2 * payRange[1]
    }
    //case 3
    if(ss1<=0 && ss2>=0 && st1<=0 && st2>=0){
        p = (ss2-st2) * payRange[1]
    }
    //case 4
    if(ss1<=0 && ss2>=0 && st2<=0 && st1<=0){
        p = ss2 * payRange[1] - st2 * payRange[0]
    }
    //case 5
    if(ss1<=0 && ss2<=0 && st1<=0 && st2<=0){
        p = (ss2-st2) * payRange[0]
    }
    //case 6
    if(ss1>=0 && ss2>=0 && st1<=0 && st2<=0){
        p = ss1 * payRange[0] + (ss2-ss1) * payRange[1] - st2 * payRange[0]
    }  
}

function getHours(time1, time2){
    var t1 = time1.split(".")[0]*60 + time1.split(".")[1]*1;
    var t2 = time2.split(".")[0]*60 + time2.split(".")[1]*1;
    return (t2-t1)/60
}
```

This is the easiest way to do this without thinking about optimizing the solution. Hope you will get an idea from this on how to implement your code.
And since I am using `<=` and `>=` operators the time range inclusions in `startime` and `stoptime` won't work. Hope you'll get some insight from this and be able to solve your problem.